# UISegmented Control switching views it resets

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UISegmentedControl and two ViewControllers. A button on each page to navigate through both views, but when I set my Segmentcontrol to a certain one and go back it resets to original.

Heres what I want to do, user on page 1 clicks settings, then UISegmentedControl chooses color scheme and goes back. (But how do I access labels from view #1)

Heres my code so far:

```
- (IBAction)colorController:(id)sender {

    if (Controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

        //App title text color
        appTitle.textColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:1.00 green:1.00 blue:0.00 alpha:1.0];

        //Background color when selected
        Controller.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.00 green:1.00 blue:0.00 alpha:1.0];

        //The font of the selected
        NSDictionary *fontColor = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [UIColor blackColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                   nil];
        [Controller setTitleTextAttributes:fontColor forState:UIControlStateSelected];


    }
    if (Controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {

        //App title text color
        appTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.00 green:0.66 blue:1.00 alpha:1.0];

        //Background color when selected
        Controller.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.00 green:0.66 blue:1.00 alpha:1.0];

        //The font of the selected
        NSDictionary *fontColor = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                   nil];
        [Controller setTitleTextAttributes:fontColor forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    }
    if (Controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {

        //App title text color
        appTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.98 green:0.22 blue:0.22 alpha:1.0];

        //Background color when selected
        Controller.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.98 green:0.22 blue:0.22 alpha:1.0];


        //The font of the selected
        NSDictionary *fontColor = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                   nil];
        [Controller setTitleTextAttributes:fontColor forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
    if (Controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 3) {

        //App title text color
        appTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.82 blue:0.44 alpha:1.0];

        //Background color when selected
        Controller.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.82 blue:0.44 alpha:1.0];

        //The font of the selected
        NSDictionary *fontColor = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
        [Controller setTitleTextAttributes:fontColor forState:UIControlStateSelected];


    }
}
```

Now. appTitle, is on View #1. So i cannot access it. plus segment control resets when i go back to view #2.

Comment: Use delegates and set manually by: `self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex`

Answer (score 1):

view #2 is probably deallocated when you go back to view #1, assuming that you pop or dismiss to go back. When you go to view #2 again, it is a new instance, so of course the segmented control will show the default selection. To change the title attributes in the first controller, you should use a delegate protocol defined in controller #2. Use it to pass the colors and font attributes back to controller #1, and let that controller set its own title characteristics. Using a delegate pattern to send data back to a previous controller is the paradigm that Apple generally uses, and you can read about it in the documentation.